# Appending a Pandas Series as a row in a DataFrame, ignoring non-matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, series

Let's say I have the following Pandas Dataframe, with no rows yet:

```
'Jeep' | 'Volvo' | 'Honda'
--------------------------
```

I have the following Pandas Series:

```
Honda    5
Nissan   3
Jeep     7
Toyota   2
```

I want to add this series as a row (not including elements that don't match a column name)

Result:

```
'Jeep' | 'Volvo' | 'Honda'
----------------------------
   7   |    0    |    5
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(); df.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])).T)`

Comment: This may not be very relevant aside for you, but `collections.Counter` handles the semantics of adding two counters, missing keys etc. much more gracefully. Also, if you have a complete list of car makes, simpler to initialize your df to it upfront, with zero counts?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Jeep', 'Volvo', 'Honda'])  
s = pd.Series({"Honda": 5, "Nissan": 3, "Jeep": 7, "Toyota": 2})  

df.append(s[df.columns], ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Nice idea, just a little tweak from mine :-)

Comment: The slightest of tweaks, haha

Comment: Lol, yeah :-) :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append` than get the specific columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Jeep', 'Volvo', 'Honda'])
>>> s = pd.Series([5, 3, 7, 2],index=['Honda', 'Nissan', 'Jeep', 'Toyota'])
>>> df1 = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
>>> df1[df.columns].fillna(0)
   Jeep  Volvo  Honda
0   7.0    0.0    5.0
>>>
```

This code is virtually:

```
>>> df1 = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
>>> df1[df.columns].fillna(0)
   Jeep  Volvo  Honda
0   7.0    0.0    5.0
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to add 'Nissan' as a column as well. I'd like it to ignore any not already in columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reindex` in a couple of different ways outlined below.

```
series.to_frame().T.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, fill_value=0)

   Jeep  Volvo  Honda
0     7      0      5
```

---

```
series.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0).to_frame().T

   Jeep  Volvo  Honda
0     7      0      5
```

---

```
df.append(series.reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0).rename(len(df)))

  Jeep Volvo Honda
0    7     0     5
```